# ValueError: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2 after replacing BatchNormalization

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, batch-normalization

I'm programming in python 3.7.5 using keras and TensorFlow 1.13.1

I want remove batch normalization layer from model coded below:

```
from keras import backend as K
from keras.callbacks import *
from keras.layers import *
from keras.models import *
from keras.utils import *
from keras.optimizers import Adadelta, RMSprop, Adam, SGD
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint
from keras.callbacks import TensorBoard

from config import *


def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    iy_pred, ilabels, iinput_length, ilabel_length = args
    # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
    # tend to be garbage:
    iy_pred = iy_pred[:, 2:, :]  # no such influence
    return K.ctc_batch_cost(ilabels, iy_pred, iinput_length, ilabel_length)


def CRNN_model(is_training=True):
    inputShape = Input((width, height, 1), name='input')  # base on         Tensorflow backend
    conv_1 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(inputShape)
    conv_2 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_1)
    #batchnorm_2 = BatchNormalization()(conv_2)
    pool_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_2)

    conv_3 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_2)
    conv_4 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_3)
    #batchnorm_4 = BatchNormalization()(conv_4)
    pool_4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_4)

    conv_5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(pool_4)
    conv_6 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(conv_5)
    pool_5 = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2))(conv_6)
    #batchnorm_6 = BatchNormalization()(conv_6)

    #bn_shape = batchnorm_6.get_shape()


    #print(bn_shape)

    #x_reshape = Reshape(target_shape=(int(bn_shape[1]), int(bn_shape[2] * bn_shape[3])))(batchnorm_6)
    #drop_reshape = Dropout(0.25, name='d1')(x_reshape)
    fl_1 = Flatten()(pool_5)
    fc_1 = Dense(256, activation='relu')(fl_1)

    #print(x_reshape.get_shape())
    #print(fc_1.get_shape())

    bi_LSTM_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal'), merge_mode='sum')(fc_1)
    bi_LSTM_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal'), merge_mode='concat')(bi_LSTM_1)

    #drop_rnn = Dropout(0.3, name='d2')(bi_LSTM_2)

    fc_2 = Dense(label_classes, kernel_initializer='he_normal', activation='softmax')(bi_LSTM_2)

    base_model = Model(inputs=[inputShape], outputs=fc_2) 

    labels = Input(name='the_labels', shape=[label_len], dtype='float32')
    input_length = Input(name='input_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')
    label_length = Input(name='label_length', shape=[1], dtype='int64')

    loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name='ctc')([fc_2, labels, input_length, label_length])

    if is_training:
        return Model(inputs=[inputShape, labels, input_length, label_length], outputs=[loss_out]), base_model
    else:
        return base_model
```

but I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Babak/PycharmProjects/CRNN-OCR/captcha-recognition-master1/captcha-recognition-master/training.py", line 79, in <module>
    model, base_model = CRNN_model(is_training=True)
  File "C:\Users\Babak\PycharmProjects\CRNN-OCR\captcha-recognition-master1\captcha-recognition-master\model.py", line 51, in CRNN_model
    bi_LSTM_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(256, return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer='he_normal'), merge_mode='sum')(fc_1)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py", line 437, in __call__
    return super(Bidirectional, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 446, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py", line 342, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer bidirectional_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How can I remove batch norm layers which is commented. I note that I manually remove drop out layers. So assume that dropout are removed. I remove dropout layers without problem. But I have problem in removing batch normalization layers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the error code, `LSTM` layers expect 3D input tensors, but `Dense` outputs only 2D. Many possible fixes exist, but not all will work equally well:

- `Conv2D` outputs 4D tensors, shaped `(samples, height, width, channels)`
- `LSTM` expects input shaped `(samples, timesteps, channels)`
- Thus, you need to somehow transform the `(height, width)` dimensions into `timesteps`

In existing research, image data is flattened and treated sequentially - however, `channels` remain untouched. Thus, a viable approach is to use `Reshape` to yield a 3D tensor shaped `(samples, height*width, channels)`. Finally, as `Dense` cannot work with 3D data, you'll need the `TimeDistributed` wrapper that'll apply the same `Dense` weights to dim 1 of input - i.e. to `timesteps`:

```py
pool_shapes = K.int_shape(pool_5)
fl_1 = Reshape((pool_shapes[1] * pool_shapes[2], pool_shapes[3]))(pool_5)
fc_1 = TimeDistributed(Dense(256, activation='relu'))(fl_1)
```

Lastly, `return_sequences=True` outputs a 3D tensor, which your output `Dense` cannot handle - so either use `return_sequences=False` to output 2D, or insert a `Flatten` before the `Dense`.

Comment: I edit my code using aforementioned 3 lines of code but get this error: fl_1 = Reshape(pool_shapes[1] * pool_shapes[2], pool_shapes[3])  # batch axis unaffected
TypeError: __init__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: @Babak.Abad Right, forgot the extra parentheses - see updated

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Now I get this error:  str(inputs) + '. All inputs to the layer '
ValueError: Layer time_distributed_1 was called with an input that isn't a symbolic tensor. Received type: <class 'keras.layers.core.Reshape'>. Full input: [<keras.layers.core.Reshape object at 0x0000019CB8F66788>]. All inputs to the layer should be tensors.

Comment: @Babak.Abad Guess I was a bit too quick again: see updated. Let me know if any other errors

Comment: @Babak.Abad You're welcome. If the problem is now solved, consider also upvoting.